# Add a field to the current record before processing in awk

Tags: awk

I want to use a large awk script that was designed to take a particular input. For example "city zipcode street housenumber", so $2 is zipcode, etc...

Now the input is provided to me in a new format. In my example "city" is now missing. The new file is "zipcode street housenumber" (not for real, just trying to make the example simple)
but I happen to know that the city is a constant for that input (which is why it's not in the dataset). So if I run it through the original script $2 is now street, and everything is one field off.

I could first process the input file to prepend the city name to each line (using awk, sed, or whatever), then run it through the original script, but I would prefer to run only one script that supports both formats. I could add a command-line option that tells it the city, but I don't know how to insert it in front of the current record at the top of the script so that the rest of the script can be unchanged. It looks like I can change a field but what I want to do is "shift" the fields right so I can modify $1.

Did I mention I am a complete awk novice? (Perl is my poison.)

Comment: so.... `awk -vcity="$city" '{ if (length(city)) { a[1] = city; a[2] = $1; a[3] = $2; } else { a[1] = $1; a[2] = $2; a[3] = $3; } }`?

Comment: doesn't that build an array that would then to be used throughout the rest of the script  so I'd have to edit the rest of the script to use a[3] instead of $3, etc...?

Comment: I'm trying to shift using: for(i=NF; i>1; --i) $(i-1)=$(i); NF+=1; but right now I can't seem to run the original script at all, all I get is (No such file or directory), so I need to solve that before I tried my shifting loop

Comment: Yes it does. You can't `shift` or `set -- arg` in awk like in bash. Use an array. `I'm trying to` `all I get is` Please update your question with sample inputs, the script that you have tried, and expected output you would like to get. Please post an [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed my own problem, I'm doing the following (haven't figured out how to do this conditionally based on a command line option, but it should be easy to find tutorials for that)

```
NF+=1;
for(i=NF; i>1; --i) $(i)=$(i-1);
$1="Vancouver";
```

I had the loop wrong in my comment above, but the basic idea of manipulating NF and copying fields into each others seems to work

Comment: Are you sure you'll never have to process an address outside the city of Vancouver?  Is that Vancouver in BC (British Columbia, Canada) or WA (Washington, USA)?

Comment: $1=mycity with mycity passed as an argument with -v mycity=Paris or whatever. Again the "city" example is not the real application, just a way to frame my question. I am now satisfied I have solved my problem in a way that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of this should do it. First some missed test data:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4
2 3 4
```

The awk:

```
$ awk -v c=V '{      # define external var
    if(NF==3)        # if record has only three fields
        $0=v FS $0   # prepend the var to the record
    print $1         # print first field 
}' file
```

Output:

```
1
V
```